# Qt not getting text from lineedit

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString username = ui->lineEdit->text();
QString password = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
QMessageBox Failed;
Failed.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

if(username == "Jon" && password == "12345")
{
    Failed.setText("Login failed. Try again.");
    Failed.exec();
} else {
    Failed.setText(password);
    Failed.exec();
}
```

Using qt.
Sorry if this has been asked before I'm quite new and couldn't find a answer.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I set username and password to the text inside the line edits on the ui. But everytime i click this button function the output of the dialog text is always blank. How can i get it so the the text is read?

Comment: Can you output `username` and `password` with `qDebug()` before the condition? That would help.

Comment: Your logic is quite strange, why you consider that login failed for one specific pair of login/password?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn basic c++ and basic qt. For this im just trying to figure out how to communicate between the ui and my code since i was fully terminal based before this.

Comment: Well, what's the output?

Comment: it outputs what i put into the box for username, but what i don't get is it wont work for my if statement. Deleted the photo for own stupidty.

Comment: Maybe test the `QMessageBox` like this: `QMessageBox Failed; Failed.setText("Hello World!"); Failed.exec();` without any condition. Will that work? And, you have switched code - if username and password match, you output "Login Failed".

Comment: Sigh, thanks LogicStuff turns out im just a moron. lineEdit 1 and 2 needed to be switched because username was password and password was username

Comment: But how come that the box didn't show nothing?

Comment: i would only type in username to test it. i never typed in password, so if password was the username it would just show up blank

Comment: *Sigh*, do you want an answer you can accept?

Comment: Do not put *Solved* into the title of the question, neither should you put any answers in the question. When you are asked to clarify, reply **by editing the question, not posting comments**. When you find a solution, you can post your own answer to the question - that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

alright, I ran some tests and this is what i found got:

if you set up some sort of signal slot connection that calls a function containg those if/else statmentsthe program will work. this is the following program i made:

dialog.h:

```
    #ifndef DIALOG_H
    #define DIALOG_H

    #include "ui_dialog.h"
    #include <QDialog>

    class DialogClass :  public QDialog, public Ui::Dialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        DialogClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    public slots:
        void check();
    };

    #endif // DIALOG_H
```

Dialog.cpp:

```
    #include "dialog.h"
    #include <QMessageBox>

    DialogClass::DialogClass(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
    {
        setupUi(this);
        connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(check()));
    }

    void DialogClass::check()
    {
        QString username = lineEdit->text();
        QString password = lineEdit_2->text();

        QMessageBox Failed;
        Failed.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

        if(username == "Jon" && password == "12345")
        {
            Failed.setText("Login failed. Try again.");
            Failed.exec();
        } else {
            Failed.setText(password);
            Failed.exec();
        }
    }
```

and main.cpp

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QMessageBox>
    #include "dialog.h"
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        DialogClass w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

bassically, all that I do is make a dialog class a lot like your main function, only that  mine has a button dialog.ui has a button. After that, I use the button to establish a signal slot connection that ensures that when this button is clicked, it will call the check() function (which is basically your if/else algorithm make into a slot), which checks to see if the username is "Jon", and password is "12345".

Why your original implementation didn't work?

I am sorry, but i am not sure.

However, this approach should work. I will add to the answer if I ever do figure out why the if statements weren't picking up. However, this approach should get your application working.

happy coding!